# Dirichlet problem on the unit disk 3

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, poissons-equation

Ive got the following problem:

Let $\mathbb{D}=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2<1\}$ be the unit disk.

Let g: $\partial \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuously differentiable
in Fourier-form: $g(e^{it})=\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}c_ke^{ikt}$

Evaluate u of the Dirichlet-Problem:

$\Delta u=0$ on $\mathbb{D}$

$u=g$ on $\partial \mathbb{D}$

in dependence of $c_k$

Tip: Use the polar form of the laplace-operator and the separation of variables.

What I did so far:

$\Delta=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \phi^2}\\
Let: \ u=R(r)Y(\phi)\\
=>\Delta u=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}R(r)Y(\phi)+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}R(r)Y(\phi)+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \phi^2}R(r)Y(\phi)$

Separation:

$\frac{r^2}{R(r)}[\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}R(r)+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}R(r)]=-\frac{1}{Y(\phi)}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \phi^2}Y(\phi)$

Now I dont know how to go further.

Im happy for every answer!

Comment: You get automatically as $u$ is harmonic that $u$ is the real part of a holomorphix resp. complex-analytic function. As a candidate function for $u(x,y)=Re(f(x+iy))$ one may try $f(z)=c_0+2\sum_{k>1}c_kz^k$

Comment: How did you get to that conclusion. Just a guess or is there a way to optain that?

Comment: $c_ke^{ikt}+\bar c_k e^{-ikt}$ on the boundary is for $z=e^{it}$ either $c_kz^k+\bar c_kz^{-k}$ which does not have a smooth continuation inside the disk, or $2Re(c_kz^k)$ which is polynomial in $x$ and $y$. So the given function conforms to the boundary conditions. One may now investigate its uniqueness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you start off with separation of variables $u(\varphi, r)=R(r)\Phi(\varphi)$
$$r^{2}\frac{R''}{R}+r\frac{R'}{R}=-\frac{\Phi''}{\Phi}=m^{2}$$
So
$$\Phi''+m^{2}\Phi=0$$
$$r^{2}R''+rR'-m^{2}R=0$$
The first equation has a periodic boundary condition $\Phi(\varphi)=\Phi(\varphi+2\pi)$, because $\varphi$ is the angular variable, the most general solution is thus
$$\Phi(\varphi)=\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}\Phi_{m}e^{im\varphi}$$
The second equation is the Euler equation and has the solution in the form
$$R(r)\propto{r^{k}}$$
This substitution gives
$$k=\pm{m}$$
So the solution is
$$R(r)=R_{m}r^{m}+R_{-m}r^{-m}$$
So, the solution to the original equation is
$$u(\varphi, r)=\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}(R'_{m}r^{m}+R'_{-m}r^{-m})e^{im\varphi}$$
Where we've defined
$$R'_{\pm{m}}=R_{\pm{m}}\Phi_{m}$$
The boundary conditions gives
$$u(\varphi, 1)=\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}(R'_{m}+R'_{-m})e^{im\varphi}=\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}c_{m}e^{im\varphi}$$
So,
$$R'_{-m}=c_{m}-R'_{m}$$
And the solution is
$$u(\varphi, r)=\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}(R'_{m}r^{m}+[c_{m}-R'_{m}]r^{-m})e^{im\varphi}$$